# Buying the correct battery

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

Looking at getting a new battery for an HP elitebook 2560p. However, there are many 9cell batteries running different mAh from 6600mAh to 9000mAh. Is there a big enough benefit in buying a 9000mAh over say a 6600mAh in longer life span? I assume a higher mAh means longer life?

Answer (score 1):

Higher mAh does mean longer life. MAh stands for milli-Ampere-hours, and is a measurement for the electric charge provided by the battery. The number is how many hours the battery could output 1 milli-ampere for before being completely discharged. The 9000 mAh battery would have a noticeably longer life, and is the better choice, as long as the cost isn't way higher than the 6600mAh battery.